# how to check for key exist in elastic-search painless parameters?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-painless

How to check for key exists in painless script map parameters.
In below query check `a.toString()` key exist in params
I've tried everything but didn't get it to work.
Please help me

mapping :

```
"id": {
   "type": "long"
}
```

query:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":[
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
               "lang": "painless",
               "params": {
                 "29232":2541,
                 "minDistance": 0
               },
               "source": "def a=doc['id'].getValue();double distance=params[a.toString()]; return distance <= 1000 && distance >= params['minDistance']"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `params` is just a Java `Map` object. So, the following checks if the `key` exists in the `params` and exits early with a `false` if it does not exist.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":[
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
               "lang": "painless",
               "params": {
                 "29232":2541,
                 "minDistance": 0
               },
               "source": """
               def a=doc['id'].getValue();
               if (!params.containsKey(a.toString())) {
                 return false;
               }
               double distance=params[a.toString()]; 
               return distance <= 1000 && distance >= params['minDistance']
               """
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it really helped me